# iisreset on remote machine (C#)

Tags: c#, iisreset

```
Process myProcess = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo remoteAdmin =
            new ProcessStartInfo(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System) + @"\iisreset.exe /restart");

remoteAdmin.UserName = username;
remoteAdmin.Password = pwd;
remoteAdmin.Domain = domain;
myProcess.StartInfo = remoteAdmin;
myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

myProcess.Start();   --- ERROR HERE
```

> Can not find the file specified.

But when I try to run iisreset on the local machine by cmd it's working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, `(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System)` will get back the local machine (Where the code is running) special folder. So it's expecting the file `C:\Windows\System\iisreset.exe` to be located on your machine. The only method I could see to get around this, is to drop the `C:\` and instead add in the device's name `\\DeviceName\C$\` and then the filepath. This is assuming the special folder system is located in the same place on your machine and the remote machine.

The only other method, to get the remote machines system directory is to get it via WMI or via a reg entry reading.

So if using WMI:

```
"SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem"
```

Once done, you would then need to build the folder string yourself from that.

Answer (score 2):

There is no file called `C:\Windows\System\iisreset.exe /restart` (assuming that `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System)` returns `C:\Windows\System\`

So you would want

```
ProcessStartInfo remoteAdmin = 
     new ProcessStartInfo(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System) + "iisreset.exe");
remoteAdmin.Arguments = "/restart";
```

But `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System)` probably returns something like `C:\Windows\System` (note no trailing slash), and there is definitely no file called `c:\windows\systemiisreset.exe`

So you would actually want

```
ProcessStartInfo remoteAdmin = 
    new ProcessStartInfo(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System), "iisreset.exe"));
remoteAdmin.Arguments = "/restart";
```

Comment: i tried this, and check the remoteAdmin.FileName on breackpoint it "c:\\windows\\system\\iisreset.exe". but myProcess.Start(); still the same error

Comment: have you verified that the file exists in that location on the server?  (it probably should).  Does the ASP.NET worker process have permission to run it?

Comment: new ProcessStartInfo(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System) + "iisreset.exe"); this code try to run iisreset on my local machine(on my machine it not exist). but Question, why its heppen, why not on remote machine? i`m a littel confused(

Answer (score 0):

iisreset.exe supports remote calls, so instead of using WMI to get remote directory you can actually just do:

```
iisreset {servername}
```

Comment: Flagged up in the lqp queue.  Alexander, can you flesh this answer out a bit more to explain what you're suggesting?