# How do i reset IIS remotely using C#.Net code?

Tags: c#, iis, windows-server-2008

I have the IIS service running on Windows Server 2008 and i want to reset it from my windows 7 machine .

How do i  reset IIS remotely using C#.Net code?

I tried using Microsoft.Web.Administration, but it doesn't accept remote server details to connect to .Any other API's that can be used for this purpose ?

Comment: Take a look at the question answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6675255/iisreset-on-remote-machine-c

Answer (score 2):

If you have a specific web site name, you can use the WMI to stop and start that web site.  If it's IIS as a whole, I'm sure there is something in the IIS WMI provider for doing this.  Here I'm using WebAdministration to manage a web site under IIS, but there's also MicrosoftIISV2.  Google for WmiExplorer, there are some good ones out there.

```
        var connOptions = new ConnectionOptions();
        connOptions.Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.PacketPrivacy;
        // if you want to connect as someone other than logged in user
        //connOptions.Username = username;
        //connOptions.Password = password;

        var scope = new ManagementScope("\\localhost\WebAdministration", connOptions);

        WqlObjectQuery query = new WqlObjectQuery(`enter code here`string.Format("SELECT * FROM Site WHERE Name = '{0}'", "Default Web Site"));

        using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query))
        {
            foreach (ManagementObject site in searcher.Get())
            {
                ManagementBaseObject inParams = site.GetMethodParameters("Stop");
                site.InvokeMethod("Stop", inParams, null);

                ManagementBaseObject inParams2 = site.GetMethodParameters("Start");
                site.InvokeMethod("Start", inParams2, null);
            }
        }
```